# How can I add CSS class to my editable element using React-TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-5

I wanted to style me editable content box with predefined CSS, either by adding a Class name but I don't see any property that enables me to do that. There is a property `body_class` but it doesn't seem to work for [react-tinymce](/questions/tagged/react-tinymce)

Here's my code

```
 <Editor
       init={{toolbar: false}}
       apiKey="xxxxx"
       inline={true}
       value="Design DIY">
  </Editor>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass CSS into the editor so that it is used to style the content while editing you need to use either the `content_css` or `content_style` configuration options.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_style

The `content_css` is likely easier as it allows you to place the CSS in an external file and reference it via a URL.

Comment: These are valid options for TinyMCE in general. I don't want use inline styling because I have been meaning to keep it one file that I can control separately so probably `content_style` is no option.  Using react, I am already importing style as `import styles from "./css/styles.css"`. How do you propose I can add class so import css, or importing it using `content_css` make sense? @michael

Comment: Also I am currently adding `className` to the parent element and giving `tagName` to the editor. In CSS I am targetting the editor via parent class. It doesn't seems to be the right way. Its just a workaround, I am sure there must be a way but I am just doesn't seem to get it.

Comment: TinyMCE is added to the page as an iframe - you cannot use the CSS you have embedded into the main page bundle hence these various settings. While I understand your desire to re-use your bundled CSS you really cannot do that in this case.

Comment: I guess then, I'll stick with the workaround. Works well. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In React you can pass your style like you pass props. [Here's a link](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp) for the documentation. But basically, you just write regular css, except for two-word properties. Those have to be written in camelCase. The link gives the example of `background-color`, has to be written `backgroundColor` as it is a JSX.

Comment: that's true, but I am talking about passing properties to plugin named TinyMCE, standard ways doesn't work for it.