# How can I complete remove menu, toolbar from editor using React-TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-5

Also, if you can help my figure out how to remove menu, unfortunately with toolbar: false, I am still able to see menu items like "File",

Here's my code

```
<Editor
    init={{toolbar: false}}
    apiKey="xxxx"
    inline={true}
    value="Design DIY">
```

My output using the above code

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide the `menubar` and `toolbar` you can do something like this:

```
// ...
<Editor
  init={{
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: false
  }}
  // other props...
/>
// ...
```

---

Use the `init` prop if you're using the official wrapper implementation https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-react.

If you're using https://github.com/instructure-react/react-tinymce use the `config` prop instead of `init`.

Comment: This was easy, thanks. Maybe you can help me with this as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63440418/how-can-i-add-style-or-css-class-to-my-editable-element-using-react-tinymce @Bas Van der Linden

Comment: BTW config is probably not the right property for TinyMCE, I haven't seen it anywhere in the docs

Comment: You're right, I've adjusted my answer. Turns out I wasn't using the official implementation.